# Is it possible to turn on session replication for embedded tomcat servers in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, session-replication

It is clear on how to do it when you have a tomcat server, but what if that server is embedded such as when you use bootJAR to build and run a tomcat webapp directly from a .jar file?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `spring-session` for store sessions in redis or jdbc

Read [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/reference/index.html) for more information